# JavaFX 8 - How to declare a TableView row factory in FXML

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, row

I have a fully functional row factory, done in java but I would like to (if possible) migrate it to my .fxml file associated with the controller. This is the working code that I currently have:

```
tableView.setRowFactory( tv -> {
            TableRow<Loan> row = new TableRow<>();
            row.setOnMouseClicked( clickEvent -> {  // If an item is clicked.
                if ((clickEvent.getClickCount() == 1) && (!row.isEmpty())) {    // Item was clicked once and the row is
                    // not empty
            });
            return row;
        });
```

Again, this works for my purposes (note that I removed what the factory does for ease of readability) but I feel like I'm not being consistent in my project by having *some* functions in the controller and some in the .fxml, it just feels wrong. I could not find anything regarding the declaration of a row factory and I hope someone out there has done it before. So far I have only done:

```
<rowFactory>

</rowFactory>
```

so I do know that there is something here to work with. But there does not seem to be any obvious choice for me to proceed such as "onMouseClicked" and so on.

Please advise!

Comment: You can't, unless you define a stand-alone class implementing the `Callback`. At that point you may as well just do it in the controller.